How is two way set associative cache better than a direct mapped cache?
I'm trying to learn computer architecture now on my own, and while I understand how two way set associative cache and direct mapped (one way) cache works from watching videos, it's not clearly what the benefit is for two way, for the same total cache size.
I know on a high level the two way version is better at avoiding collisions, but it's not immediately obviously how. I hope someone can provide a toy example to help me get a concrete understanding of it. For example, accessing an array of integers...
Let's assume each cache block is 8 bytes, and each integer is 4 byte (32 bits), so each cache block can hold 2 elements of the array.
Total cache size is 128 bytes. So in the direct mapped version there would be 16 cache blocks. In the two way set associative version, there'd be 2 ways, with 8 cache blocks in each way. So a "set" would be 2 cache blocks with 8 bytes in each block.
Thanks

Please show an example of an access pattern where this difference in mapping makes a difference in miss rate. Argue which is worse, and what are reasons for using it regardless.
